# ASP.net MVC Action URLs with lambda expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda, action, asp.net-mvc-futures, magic-string

I'm sure I have seen this syntax

```
<%= Url.Action((MyController c) => c.MyMethod("a")) %>
```

or something like it as a way to generate action URLs in ASP.net MVCs without magic strings. However, I can't find that Action overload. I have ASP.NET MVC 1.0. Where is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need [ASP.NET MVC v1.0 Futures](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471#DownloadId=61773) assembly:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink<MyController>(x => x.MyMethod(a), "text") %>

<%= Html.BuildUrlFromExpression<MyController>(x => x.MyMethod(a)) %>
```